# Significance of "seed" in weka K means clustering

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining, k-means

The [weka SimpleKMeans](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/SimpleKMeans.html) implementation allows the user to specify a "seed value" with the option -s. I do not understand what it signifies. In [this link](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?72720-SimpleKMeans-Clustering-in-WEKA), Mark Hall, the weka architect, says that it is supposed to generate random numbers.

Weka implementation is supposed to follow the paper on [KMenas++](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf) (as mentioned in the documentation), and if I have understood it, cluster centroid points are decided using the equation 1b, section 2.2 page 3 in the [aforementioned paper](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf), and there is no other source of randomness.

Can anyone please point out that what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a common *best practise* with k-means algorithms (note: there is more than one algorithm for k-means; they are heuristics as finding the optimal solution is reported to be NP-hard) to **do multiple iterations with different random initial centers**.

So the randomness is commonly involved with choosing the initial centers. K-means++ is an alternate way of choosing initial seeds that *fortunately* is still randomized (there are some that are not randomized, so you can no longer try to improve your results with multiple runs then), but tries to choose a better starting situation.

Why are you looking for *another* source of randomness than the inital means?

I don't recommend Weka for clustering. It is okay for classification, but it has quite limited support for clustering and other unsupervised methods. Instead, have a look at ELKI. their [k-means package](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/kmeans) for example is quite exhaustive. They have ~6 different methods for choosing the initial means. Most are randomized. The simplest and most common intialization is probably to just start with k random objects from the database. IIRC, MacQueen used the first k objects, so that variant is not randomized (unless you shuffle your data set first, which actually is a good idea for quite some algorithms - never use sorted data!)
Most of these initializers will therefore come with a parameter `-kmeans.seed` which - guess what - allows you to control the random generator seeding, for reproducible results.

Comment: And of course, it's good practice to have an explicit (optional) random seed argument for any randomized algorithm, since it permits reproducible results.

Comment: I am not looking for another source of randomness. But, I didn't find the significance of "seed" in the implementation. However, thanks for pointing out the package.